# Return a variable-sized array from C to Java

Tags: java, c, arrays, java-native-interface, swig

I'm using the SWIG library to let a Java (Android) app call C functions.

I need to have some of my C functions return variable-sized arrays back to Java. How can I do this?

I've considered converting a long long * to a jlongarray, but I don't know how to pass the jlongarray back to Java with SWIG.

Does anyone know the best way to pass a variable-sized array from C to Java with SWIG (or any way at all)?

Comment: Have you looked at the SWIG manual? Try couple of things there (discusses arrays in several places) then you might want to update your question to be more specific, you'll get more help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to make a custom typemap in SWIG, but I got segfaults when I did that.

I eventually solved the problem by writing a new function in straight JNI that puts the array elements into a jlongArray, rather than letting SWIG write a wrapper function for it.